# Using a sigaction handler with sigaction when SA_SIGINFO is not set

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals

The [spec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) says that

> If SA_SIGINFO is specified in sa_flags, then sa_sigaction
> (instead of sa_handler) specifies the signal-handling function
> for signum.

However, the following code works magically

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *uc){
   printf("si = %d\n", *(char*)si);
   printf("uc = %d\n", *(char*)uc);
}

int main(void)
{
      struct sigaction psa;
      psa.sa_flags = 0;
      psa.sa_sigaction = handler;
      sigaction(SIGTSTP, &psa, NULL);
      for(;;) {}
      return 0;
}
```

handler is able to access memories at si and ui, and gdb shows that at least si is indeed a pointer to siginfo_t. However, the [code](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/sigaction.h.html) implements sa_sigaction and sa_handler as a union. If the runtime uses sa_flags to decide to use sa_sigaction or sa_handler, it seems hard to know sa_sigaction should be used...

Does this mean the runtime always provides si and uc to both the two kinds of calls? Is such a user code well-defined?

Comment: It's less code to just pass the extra args regardless [which it _is_ doing, based on your test results]. It doesn't "harm" an `sa_handler` [you can always pass more args than the signature specifies and the 1st arg is an `int`] It's a bit of a moot point. Your code is setting the _wrong_ struct member and is "getting away with it" because of the union. If you really need to know, pull the [linux] kernel source and track down the code that sets this.  This is linux, but on another posix sys, this may not work (i.e. not a union).

Comment: It doesn't say what the behaviour will be if the code does otherwise. So it's a classic undefined behaviour. If you write code like that then be prepared for it to break at some point.

Comment: BTW, `printf` -> `malloc` -> _not_ signal safe

Answer (score 0):

> *Does this mean the runtime always provides si and uc to both the two kinds of calls?*

It means that particular implementation does, yes.

> Is such a user code well-defined?

No, it means that it relies on undefined behavior that happens to work on one particular platform.

Note that, even on your present platform, this shortcut might not work for you.  You could forgive your runtime for itself taking a shortcut with garbage in the `siginfo_t` and `ucontext_t` parameters.  After all, by not omitting SA_SIGINFO, you told the implementation that you wouldn't need that information.